# Jquery ui slider with flip counter effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I want to implement jQuery ui flip counter plug-in like this http://demo.cnanney.com/apple-counter-revisited/ . but my requirement is that unlike to demo where the range sliders are used for increment and pace value. But in my case I want the two ui slider values to be multiplied and displayed as output with flip counter effect.

Here is the code: HTML and JS

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="counter-wrapper">
    <ul class="flip-counter default" id="myCounter"></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="demo_controls">
  <li>
    <p>Increment: <span id="inc_value">85</span></p>

    <div id="inc_slider" class="demo_widget"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Pace: <span id="pace_value">9</span></p>

    <div id="pace_slider" class="demo_widget"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the script i am trying to work out to display the multiplication value of two sliders into id with mycounter,

```
<script>

  $(function(){
    function updateAmounts() {

    var value1 = $('#inc_value').slider('value');

    var value2 = $('#pace_value').slider('value');

    $('#myCounter').val((value1 * value2) * valueMultiplier);

    }
    var valueMultiplier = 12;

    $('#inc_slider').slider({
      range: 'max',
      value: 85,
      min: 0,
      max: 332,
      slide: function(event, ui){
        $('#inc_value').text(ui.value);
        updateAmounts();
      }
    });

    // Pace
    $('#pace_slider').slider({
      range: 'max',
      value: 9,
      min: 0,
      max: 18,
      step: 3,
      slide: function(event, ui){
        $("#pace_value").text(ui.value);
        updateAmounts();
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2642/?

Comment: thanks for the reply, mathematical calculation was exactly what i want..but how to make sure we have the flip counter effect to stay for the output as it was in that demo...as our output is updating based on the sliders, how can we acheive this with same ui (output having flip-counter effect)